# Is it possible to use explicit huge pages in redis

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, redis

I know that Redis does not work well with THB (Transparent Huge Pages),
but is it possible to run Redis using explicit 2MB or 1GB HugePages?

Unfortunately googling the issue always gives a ton of info about THP but none about HugeTLB.

Is it possible and if yes then how could I run Redis using HugeTLB?